# How to change DIV order by CSS

Tags: html, css

Suppose there is one parent div and five child divs. Now when we don't apply CSS they will be placed one below another.

How to change the position of 3rd div so that it can either be above 1st div or wherever I want to place it, it can be below 2nd div or 4th div. How can we do that using CSS?

Note - The HTML cannot be changed.

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child1">
    1
  </div>

  <div class="child2">
    2
  </div>

  <div class="child3">
    3
  </div>

  <div class="child4">
    4
  </div>

  <div class="child5">
    5
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: [CSS order](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order)

Comment: This can be done with flexbox or grid. Have you learnt those? I suggest learning basic CSS properties before doing interviews where CSS is asked ;)

Comment: You need to use `order` property in css. so read documentation here [LINK #1](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_order.asp) or [LINK #2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use **flex** or **grid** box and then you able to change **order** of it's child elements. Take a look at [this DOC page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order)

```css
/* this will make your container flex */
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

/* 
  change order of your child element 
  possible selectors:
    - class: .child3
    or
    - without child class: .parent > div:nth-child(3)
*/
.child3 {
  order: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child1">
    1
  </div>

  <div class="child2">
    2
  </div>

  <div class="child3">
    3
  </div>

  <div class="child4">
    4
  </div>

  <div class="child5">
    5
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're allowed to style the parent div, you could use display flex and flex-direction column. Then apply the [order](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order) property to the children, so you could to align them to your liking.